# Generating SQLite Results

Tags: sql, database, sqlite, database-design

So I'm brand new to databases and SQLite, and I have a pretty simple question for you.
If I were to create a database with the following tables, and data, how would I generate a result set that will give me a table with all of the events lined up with each of their venues? Specifically, what is the SQLite query? Thanks so much!

```
create table if not exists venues(
          venueId integer primary key not null, --auto increment key 
          capacity int, 
          country text, 
          street text, 
          city text  
    );

create table if not exists hostedAt(
      venueId integer not null,
      eventId integer not null
);

create table if not exists events(
      eventId integer primary key not null, --auto increment key 
      time int, 
      name text,  
      price text,
      eventDate text, 
      type text

);

insert into events(time, name, price, eventDate, type) values (4 , 'Bluesfest' , '$300' , 'July 4', 'Concert');
insert into events(time, name, price, eventDate, type) values (4 , 'Folk Fest' , '$200' , 'August 14', 'Concert');
insert into events(time, name, price, eventDate, type) values (4 , 'Rave Fest' , '$100' , 'May 10', 'Rave');

insert into venues(capacity, country, street, city) values (1000, 'Canada', 'Lebreton Flats', 'Ottawa');
insert into venues(capacity, country, street, city) values (300, 'Canada', 'Bank Street', 'Ottawa');

insert into hostedAt(venueId, eventId) values (1,1);
insert into hostedAt(venueId, eventId) values (1,2);
insert into hostedAt(venueId, eventId) values (2,3);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to join all 3 tables by using middle lockup table.

Your query will be as following

```
SELECT e.*
       ,v.*
    FROM events as e
    JOIN hostedat as h
        ON e.eventid = h.eventid
    JOIN venues as v
        ON h.venueid = v.venueid
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select * -- or just the fields that you require.
from       events ev
inner join hostedAt ho
on         ho.eventId = ev.eventId
inner join venues ve
on         ve.venueId = ho.venueId
```

In your example i see a problem coming up when your autoincrement-filling of the ID fields doesn't matchup with manual filling of the hostedAt table.
Or is that just to keep your example simple?

So, when you insert a value in events or venues, you have got to catch the inserted id's to use them in the insert for table hostedAt.

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you mean by this. Could you elaborate a little more?

Thanks for your help.